# File named index.php needed in URL

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, httpd.conf

While Codeigniter is hosted on Godaddy or Speedhost, URL works like - http://www/host_name.com/admin/home but it doesn't work on Amazon's Linux AMI instance or Even with Ubuntu Instance as we need to introduce the index.php in between in URL as shown below - http://www/host_name.com/index.php/admin/home

I have .htaccess file included in project root (here, admin_portal) but still there won't be any success. Below are the contents of my .htaccess file.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: Try with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]` or `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]` or `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [L,QSA]` instead your actual last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled.

If have apache running as your webserver and you have access to the command shell on your instances, you can use...

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

then restart the server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for inputs.. 

Actually, it solved for me using below settings in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf of apache server

change All AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All.

Comment: Yes that would definitely help!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php    [R=301,L]
```